# How to add prompt input value to array after switch statement?

Tags: javascript, arrays, switch-statement

I have created an array with 10 names hard coded in as an existing database.

I am struggling to get the user input value from the prompt of option 1 and push it to the array.

```
let userList = ["Sarah","Bryan","Scott","Mirande","Tamzin","Tamryn","Steven","Peter","Skippi","Sheldon"]
console.log(userList)

let menu = prompt("===== Menu ===== \n" + "What would you like to do?\n\n" + "1.Add three Users\n" + "2.Remove User\n" +
"3.Display all users \n" + "4.Sort users \n")

let choice = menu;

switch(choice){

    case '1':
        prompt("Add 3 User");
        break;

    case '2':
        prompt("Remove User");
        break;

    case '3':
        alert("Users have been displayed");
        break;

    case '4':
       prompt("Sort users");
        break;
    
    default:
        alert("Please refresh browser");
        break;
}

console.log(choice);
console.log(userList);
```

I am aware that `userList.push()` is a method that is used to push something into the userList array, i am just not sure how to do it after the wtich statement when the user has inserted the 3 names.

Comment: What's the point of the prompts (for example, "Add 3 User") within the switch statement? What are you asking for here? You don't save those values to a variable, so they are not going to do anything.

Comment: Why add 3 users? But you are only allowed to type 1 user and thats it?

Comment: `case '1': let newUser = prompt("Add 3 User"); userList.push(newUser); break;` if You want to push the user from your command prompt to your array but then again, you will insert only 1 user not 3 like your text says

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this if you need to push 3 different users to your array after selecting option 1 once

```js
let userList = ["Sarah","Bryan","Scott","Mirande","Tamzin","Tamryn","Steven","Peter","Skippi","Sheldon"]
console.log(userList)

let menu = prompt("===== Menu ===== \n" + "What would you like to do?\n\n" + "1.Add three Users\n" + "2.Remove User\n" +
"3.Display all users \n" + "4.Sort users \n")

let choice = menu;

switch(choice){

    case '1':
      const userInput1 = prompt('Add 1st Users');
      const userInput2 = prompt('Add second User');
      const userInput3 = prompt('Add third User');
      userList.push(userInput1);
      userList.push(userInput2);
      userList.push(userInput3);
    break;

    case '2':
        prompt("Remove User");
        break;

    case '3':
        alert("Users have been displayed");
        break;

    case '4':
       prompt("Sort users");
        break;
    
    default:
        alert("Please refresh browser");
        break;
}

console.log(choice);
console.log(userList);
```

or push all 3 users to array in one line

```
userList.push(userInput1, userInput2, userInput3);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the save the prompt into a variable to use it.

Inside "case 1" you can do it like this and so on.

```
case '1':
const x = prompt('Add 3 User');
userList.push(x);
console.log(userList);
break;
```